# Behaviour of Javascript and Java on PlayN is different

Tags: java, javascript, playn

When I build the PlayN project and run the **java** version, it's behaviour is different to when I run the **HTML** version.

Basically I made a board game that uses a modified version of the Minimax algorithm (search tree and weighting evaluation) for its AI.

Since nothing is calculated randomly, and if the inputs are the same, I'd expect the outputs to be the same too.

However, the AI's of the java and javascript (HTML) versions behave differently to the same input.

The link to the **Html/javascript** version can be found here:
http://mugle-app.appspot.com/+games/staff/fiar/

The **java** (JAR) file can be found at:
http://ez-playn.googlecode.com/files/FiarJava.zip

They both use the **same code**, only compilations have been different, but both using the provided Ant scripts. Tree depth is fixed, evaluator weightings are fixed

I can't understand why there would be a difference since every thing works except the search tree...could it be because that evaluation is heavy and javascript run's out of resources?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How can a Java program have the "same code" as a JavaScript program? (Do I need to list the fundamental differences between the two languages?) Have you tried debugging the programs, perhaps stepping through the essential functions/methods (focusing on the search tree, since that's where you seem to be saying the problem lies)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I may have not been clear, sorry about that. When I meant the "same code", I meant the "core" section of the game (which is written in Java) is constant. The compilers provided by PlayN convert the code into javascript (similar to GWT). Hence, its starting source code is the "same", but the compiled versions are different. Therefore, I can't debug the javascript since I don't write the javascript portion of it. The only section I can really debug is the java portion of it. Thanks and hope this made it clear :)

Comment: In case you haven't used the PlayN library, this is the link https://developers.google.com/playn/. It lets us write a single piece of code in java and they compile it to may other platforms such as javascript (for HTML), android and flash.

Comment: You can debug the JavaScript version (or _any_ JavaScript running in a browser whether you wrote it or not) by using your browser's developer tools. Google "how to debug javascript in [your browser's name here]".

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll give it a try. :) But my initial question still remains, could this be a fault in the converter?

Comment: Oh I just realised, the function names after converting have been renamed to short random names (stripped down version) for optimisation. It's gonna be a nightmare debugging this :P

Comment: I haven't got time to go look at your code and compare (especially when identifier names have been stripped down), but some fault in the converter seems likely.

Comment: Thanks for your time and patience :) I'll post back if I find something.

Comment: The Jar file you provided does not have any of your source code in it. It has a bunch of class files and the source for playn-core and pythagoras. Can you provide your actual source code? If not I can give you tips on debugging the JavaScript, but the behavior should be identical to Java assuming that the code is deterministic.

Comment: @samskivert Thanks for the reply. I have updated the jar file with the source, however, I need to say that it is NOT well documented as I wasn't planning to release the code anytime soon. I'm sure the algorithm is deterministic but debugging 4~5 depths in the recursive tree can be a nightmare as I've spent days fixing bugs on that already. :P Additionally, you should be able to run the java game (java -jar) and the HTML using the link; and you'd notice the behavioural difference. Thanks for your time and I'm a big fan of the PlayN authors! :D

Comment: I looked briefly at the source and didn't find anything that looked likely to cause divergence between the GWT-compiled and javac-compiled versions. I suspect maybe you're triggering some GWT bug. If you have the time to generate a trace of the search and compare the traces between the bytecode and JavaScript versions, that would be very informative. Otherwise I'll try to do that myself at some point since I'm curious about what's going wrong.

Comment: I'll only be able to do that after next week as I've got exams next week. I've paused development for now due to exams, but I'll be resuming work on this after the 26th (weekend). Please go ahead if you have the time to look at it before me. If not, can you please guide me of an easier way to trace the javascript as the GWT-compiler has stripped of identifier names. Thanks!

Comment: @samskivert I had a quick look at the two traces. The thing I noticed was that all vector implementations in java are converted to  linked lists in JS. So the AI, when traversing the valid cells for evaluation, the order is somewhat different. In the AI of this game, the order in which the cells are evaluated is crucial as the list is not sorted; if there are multiple cells with the same weighting, it picks the last it encounters. Since the order of the items in the lists are different, the selected move ends up being different; also propagates to the lower depths of the tree. Hope it helps..

Comment: The test I did was, make the move (6,3) and the java version AI ends up doing (3,0) whereas the JS is (0,3). I traced only the first depth (depth=0) and in java (3,0) is evaluated before (3,6), but in the JS (3,6) is evaluated before (3,0). And their overall weightings were different in java and JS. So my first guess is that the propagation of this bug (or issue) caused the weightings to be different. Finally, forcing the java version to pick (3,0) as the final move and JS being (0,3). Note that edge-center cells are highly weighted, hence the swap between (0,3) and (3,0).

Comment: You're not using any class named Vector. What do you mean when you say Vector? Do you mean ArrayList? Because that's not converted into a linked list in JavaScript, it's converted to a JavaScript array, which has the same ordering properties as ArrayList. You explicitly use LinkedList in your code, so naturally that code would remain a LinkedList in JavaScript. However, LinkedList also has predictable ordering properties that will not change between Java and JavaScript. What could cause a problem is if you are iterating over the keys or values of a HashMap or a HashSet. Are you doing that?

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. The reason I mistakenly said vector was because earlier I copied the contents from the HashMap to a vector and passed the vector around. But later on I changed it to a LinkedList. Hence the javascript conversion ended up beign a linked list too which I missed, while doing my quick debugging session. Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are iterating over the contents of a HashMap. `Board` defines `emptyCells` which is a HashMap, and then `GameSearch` calls `Board.getEmptyCellCollection` (which returns the values of the HashMap as a collection) and then iterates over them. Those values *do not* have a predictable ordering, and the ordering will almost certainly change in the conversion from Java to JavaScript.

If you need to iterate over the contents of a HashMap in predictable order, use LinkedHashMap.

Comment: Changing to LinkedHashMap changed the behaviour of the Java game towards the Javascript version. However, I think I'll have to tune the values some more, because this is not the desired behaviour I wanted for the AI. Nevertheless, your solution worked! Thanks! :D